# Retrieve color image back from grayscaled image in python

Tags: python, opencv

Currently i am working on a project in which i need to convert an image into grayscale and then reset the image back to its original color.

I am not getting how to retrieve back the original image after converting it into grayscale.

The code is:

```
img = Image.open('input/img_6847.jpg')
imggray = img.convert('LA')
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))
plt.imshow(imggray);
```

Now i want to get this image imggray back to the original one which i opened. How can this be implemented?

Comment: It is not possible to convert it back from a greyscale conversion since is a lossy conversion. However, you can try reloading the image, or saving a copy in another variable.

Comment: `backtorgb = cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)`

Comment: @RickM. this command is not able to retrieve the original colors back and barely makes a difference.

Comment: As @api55 mentioned, it is a lossy conversion

Comment: Some machine learning techniques may be able to recover the colors, however it requires more effort to implement them and then train them. Also, it may not recover the correct colors, but something that it thinks it is correct

Comment: @api55 yes i understood what you conveyed and so i an up towards finding another way for the problem itself :)
Thanks!

Comment: @RickM. Yes i understood :) Thankyou

Comment: See this deep learning technique: [Colorful Image Colorization](https://richzhang.github.io/colorization/)

Comment: Additionally, without machine learning techniques (might be an overkill), if you give as `gray` in the code in my comment and instead of using a _normal_ gray image you give it as some kind of a color map, the function should be able to retrieve close to your original image. But it depends on what [color map](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html#gadf478a5e5ff49d8aa24e726ea6f65d15) you give.